# C# listview multi row select SQL Server update

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a listview that is populated with multiple rows and columns and selecting one row and updating the database is working fine, but when I select multiple rows and try to update the database it's just updating the first selected row.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

```
private void updateinline()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.listView1.SelectedItems) 
    {
        string fnumber1 = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text.ToString();
        string fname1 = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
        string lname1 = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text.ToString();
        string grade1 = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text.ToString();
        string connectionString = "Server=TechSQL; database=Student_Pickup; Integrated Security=True;";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE WBT SET In_Line = @date WHERE Family_Number = @fnumber1 AND First_Name = @fname1 AND Last_Name = @lname1 AND Grade = @grade1");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", sqlFormattedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnumber1", fnumber1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname1", fname1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname1", lname1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade1", grade1);

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0]` etc is always the first item, you need to use `itemRow` which changes within the loop.

Comment: Better to open the connection once, outside the loop.

Comment: Also storing dates as strings is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks guys, just changed them to:             string fnumber1 = listView1.SelectedItems[i].SubItems[0].Text.ToString();

Comment: You should be able to just `itemRow.SubItems[0] ...` and so on